# How do you reduce this image size?

Tags: css, html

I'm currently using DYI app builder platform and they have a <>source code page.  So I put in

```
<img src="URL.png"/>
```

And it worked! But when I tried to shrink the image (original image is width=256 height 256)

```
<img src="URL.png" Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

Nothing happens to the size of the image.

So I tried

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow:hidden;" >
```

`<img src="URL.png" width="100px" height="auto">` 
`</div>`

Which I picked up on StackOverflow.. But it doesn't work.

Please help. BTW I have no knowledge of coding so please do not skip a step assuming I would know it.

(When I apply the code and go back to the source code page width and height disappeared from the source code page except the bare bone Img src="URL")

Comment: Either way should work - if not - then there's something in the app builder overriding it.  Impossible for us to help if we don't even know what DYI app builder platform you are using.
You could also try using !important:

<img src="URL.png" style="width:100px !important; height:100px !important;">

Answer (score 1):

Something in your program is overriding it or disabling it (filtering it away). If it is another css rule that is overriding your css, then you could try:

```
width:100px !important;height:100px !important;
```

if this doesn't work then apparently the css gets filtered out, you might check the program's settings if this behavior can be changed

Answer (score 1):

Try to **save** the page, in the DYI app builder you're using.